Overflow using `animated_tree_view`
Using animated_tree_view to render a tree, but I am running out of horizontal space relatively quickly (around level 9) and a RenderFlex overflow is being thrown.
A RenderFlex overflowed by 22 pixels on the right.

I tried wrapping it with a ListView or SingleChildScrollView with a horizontal scroll direction, but that throws a different rendering issue because no explicit horizontal space (width) is given. However, manually adding a preset width like 5000 seems like a hacky way to solve it.
Ideally, a user should only scroll horizontally when an overflow has occurred. Otherwise, I would be okay with some panning.
EDIT: Here is the example code--keep clicking the add icon until you get the same overflow:
import 'package:animated_tree_view/animated_tree_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimatedTreeExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedTreeExample({super.key});

  @override
  AnimatedTreeExampleState createState() => AnimatedTreeExampleState();
}

class AnimatedTreeExampleState extends State<AnimatedTreeExample> {
  TreeViewController? _controller;
  TreeNode<dynamic> selectedNode = sampleTree;
  int addOperations = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: TreeView.simple(
        tree: sampleTree,
        expansionBehavior: ExpansionBehavior.snapToTop,
        expansionIndicatorBuilder: (context, node) =>
            ChevronIndicator.rightDown(
          tree: node,
          color: Colors.black,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        ),
        indentation: const Indentation(
          color: Colors.black,
          style: IndentStyle.squareJoint,
          thickness: 1,
        ),
        onItemTap: (item) {
          if (kDebugMode) print("Item tapped: ${item.key}");
        },
        onTreeReady: (controller) {
          _controller = controller;
        },
        builder: (context, node) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text("Item ${node.level}-${node.key}"),
              subtitle: Row(
                children: [
                  Text('Level ${node.level}'),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (selectedNode != node) {
                          selectedNode = node;
                        }

                        addOperations += 1;

                        selectedNode
                            .add(TreeNode(key: '${node.key}$addOperations'));
                      },
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

final sampleTree = TreeNode.root()
  ..addAll([
    TreeNode(key: "0A")..add(TreeNode(key: "0A1A")),
    TreeNode(key: "0C")
      ..addAll([
        TreeNode(key: "0C1A"),
        TreeNode(key: "0C1B"),
        TreeNode(key: "0C1C")
          ..addAll([
            TreeNode(key: "0C1C2A")
              ..addAll([
                TreeNode(key: "0C1C2A3A"),
                TreeNode(key: "0C1C2A3B"),
                TreeNode(key: "0C1C2A3C"),
              ])
          ]),
      ]),
    TreeNode(key: "0D"),
    TreeNode(key: "0E"),
  ]);


Hello, can you attach the codes to the question?

@SemihYilmaz Sure, I added example code above. Hit the "add" icon until an overflow appears--since it will be different based on your device/resolution.
